# Why Lagrange's Theorem implies $|G/K|$ divides $p!$ (proof of Corollary $5$ on page $120$ of Dummit and Foote)

Tags: group-theory

In the proof of Corollary $5$ on page $120$ of Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, I don't understand why Lagrange's Theorem implies that $|G/K|$ divides $p!$.

Here is an excerpt.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_p$, which has order $p!$.

Comment: But this has anything to do with Lagrange theorem?

Comment: And why the order of Sp is p!?

Comment: @Joseph: The fact that $|S_p| = p!$ is proved in section 1.3. It should then be clear how the claim follows from Lagrange's Theorem. If it is not clear to you, I recommend you reread the statement of Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: @Micheal Albanese: Sorry, I forgot the definition of Sn.